# Class to enforce local style for links in css

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a set of toolbar buttons that I want to use specific styles on.

Some global css (via bootstrap) styles :visited links and colours them and I want it to stop doing that in this area...

I'd like to use a css class that basically says:

Anything beneath me only listen to locally defined styles on

```
color:
bg-color:
text-decoration:
```

i.e. if I define the style within that class, then listen to my color definition above all else. Where my definition might be to add

```
class: text-success
```

Hope that makes sense to someone.

Comment: Try to put your style under bootstrap, then your style will override the bootstrap style

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't simply define the class and have it loaded after the bootstrap styles (which permanently overrides bootstrap on that page), then you will need to define that class in your .css file, and add it dynamically at the appropriate place/time using javascript.